# Extracting divs with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, xpath, scrapy

I have an `html` document with several different (but related) `div` classes. For instance:

```
<div class="title_dep1"></div>
<div class="title_dep2"></div>
<div class="title_dep3"></div>
```

I would like to instruct response.xpath to return all of them. I was thinking anything like a regular expression on digits would do, like

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="title_dep[\d]+"]').extract()
```

But you cannot do that. What is the best way to retrieve all `div`s in the format above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **`contains`**:

```
from lxml import html

HTML = """<div class="title_dep1">Hi Dervin</div>
<div class="title_dep2">This is the way to grab</div>
<div class="title_dep3">Different divs with the same prefix in @class attribute</div>"""

data = html.fromstring(HTML)
print data.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"title_dep")]/text()')
```

Or you could use **`re`** (regular expression) inside your XPath:

```
print data.xpath('//div[re:match(@class, "title_dep\d+")]/text()', namespaces={"re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"})
```

> You need to give the namespace mapping, so that it knows what the **"re"** prefix in the xpath expression stands for.

**Output is the same for both:**

```
['Hi Dervin', 'This is the way to grab', 'Different divs with the same prefix in @class attribute']
```

Comment: @DervinThunk I'm glad my answer helped. I've updated it with one more example with regex :)